# Know where the screen is being clicked or touched in Unity 2d

Tags: unity

I'm making a flappy bird game. I want when the player touches the screen or clicks the bird to "jump". This part I have already done. The problem is that on my screen I also have a button and when I press it either by clicking or tapping the screen the game interacts with the button (which is fine) but it also makes the bird jump which I don't want. What do I do so that when I press the button it only interacts with the button but when I press any other part of the screen (which is what interests me) the bird jumps?

Here I show you a method that returns true if the player has clicked or touched the screen, I want it to be executed only when I click on the screen and not when I click on a button:

```
void Update(){   
    Up();
}

void Up(){
    if(DetectJump()){
        //the bird jumps
    }
}

bool DetectJump(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) ||
     Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began ||
     Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
         return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: You can find existing Q&A demonstrating how to fix this: [UI clicks hitting game objects below](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134504/39518), [Clicking pause button makes character jump before pausing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108915/39518). Usually these solutions first check whether the pointer is over a UI button using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`, and disregarding the click if this function returns `true`. Be sure to search for past Q&A, tutorials, and documentation to find this information faster next time.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me